# Maximo Anywhere Map Location Issue

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am using Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2 (Work Execution App). I have made the necessary changes in .properties files for MAP. I need to see some location in Map (Online), I have added some location data (Lat,Long) in MAM but couldn't get the same in device.

Logs:

```
2016-01-22 10:46:51.400 WorkExecution[1689:755353] got show busy call
2016-01-22 10:46:51.401 WorkExecution[1689:755353] showing busy indicator
2016-01-22 10:46:51.401 WorkExecution[1689:755353] WARN: Loading message showed by application = true
2016-01-22 10:46:51.403 WorkExecution[1689:755353] WARN: Show View WorkExecution.MapView
2016-01-22 10:46:51.404 WorkExecution[1689:755353] WLReachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
2016-01-22 10:46:51.407 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TIMER] Create Resources:WorkExecution.MapView: 9ms
2016-01-22 10:46:51.407 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [MapHandler] added listener, count 1
2016-01-22 10:46:51.407 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] MapHandler setCurrentMarker
2016-01-22 10:46:51.408 WorkExecution[1689:755353] asked to hide busy indicator
2016-01-22 10:46:51.432 WorkExecution[1689:755353] got managebusy call busystate=false, busy window visible=true
2016-01-22 10:46:51.432 WorkExecution[1689:755695] [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth
2016-01-22 10:46:51.433 WorkExecution[1689:755353] taking down busy window
2016-01-22 10:46:51.433 WorkExecution[1689:755353] WARN: Loading message hidden by application = true
2016-01-22 10:46:51.433 WorkExecution[1689:755353] WARN: Loading message hidden
2016-01-22 10:46:51.437 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] -[NotificationEx loadingStop:] in NotificationEx.m:150 :: Loading stop
2016-01-22 10:46:51.444 WorkExecution[1689:755353] THREAD WARNING: ['NotificationEx'] took '11.097900' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2016-01-22 10:46:51.461 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [WARN] [USER_CERT_AUTH] +[WLUserAuthManager getCertificateIdentifier] in WLUserAuthManager.m:68 :: Certificate Identifier Key: com.worklight.userenrollment.certificate:com.WorkExecution
2016-01-22 10:46:51.472 WorkExecution[1689:755353] THREAD WARNING: ['UserAuth'] took '11.177979' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2016-01-22 10:46:51.494 WorkExecution[1689:755695] [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists:  false
2016-01-22 10:46:51.569 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:196 :: Request Success
2016-01-22 10:46:51.571 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:197 :: Response Status Code : 200
2016-01-22 10:46:51.574 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:198 :: Response Content : /*-secure-
{"userInfo":{"wl_directUpdateRealm":{"userId":"null","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"null","deviceId":"null"},"CustomAuthenticationRealm":{"isSuccessful":true,"userId":"maxadmin","attributes":{"Cookie":"JSESSIONID=0000-SkE1FAXWL8ftNRYI9N1xmN:-1; Path=\/; HttpOnly","AuthenticationDate":"Fri Jan 22 10:46:04 MYT 2016"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":null,"deviceId":"maxadmin"},"wl_authenticityRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"wl_remoteDisableRealm":{"userId":"null","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"null","deviceId":"null"},"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"userId":"c41pcfh3e92rspokaktj2be62i","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"c41pcfh3e92rspokaktj2be62i","deviceId":"c41pcfh3e92rspokaktj2be62i"},"wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":"0F2EE785-4184-4BC2-8C76-3B7CE840F38D","attributes":{"mobileClientData":"com.worklight.core.auth.ext.MobileClientData@dfd2569f"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"0F2EE785-4184-4BC2-8C76-3B7CE840F38D","deviceId":"0F2EE785-4184-4BC2-8C76-3B7CE840F38D"},"myserver":{"userId":"fcd2bad6-4ca1-4d40-9e02-ea3f23ec61c1","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"fcd2bad6-4ca1-4d40-9e02-ea3f23ec61c1","deviceId":"fcd2bad6-4ca1-4d40-9e02-ea3f23ec61c1"},"wl_anonymousUserRealm":{"userId":"fcd2bad6-4ca1-4d40-9e02-ea3f23ec61c1","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"fcd2bad6-4ca1-4d40-9e02-ea3f23ec61c1","deviceId":"fcd2bad6-4ca1-4d40-9e02-ea3f23ec61c1"}},"userPrefs":{},"gadgetProps":{"ENVIRONMENT":"iphone"}}*/
2016-01-22 10:46:51.679 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [CustomChallangeHandler.isCustomResponse] false
2016-01-22 10:46:51.680 WorkExecution[1689:755353] No matching configurations found from the server. Defaulting to local configuration
2016-01-22 10:46:51.680 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TIMER] [COMM] Fetching device for connectivity: 549ms
2016-01-22 10:46:51.681 WorkExecution[1689:755695] [DEBUG] [NONE] response [/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/iphone/init] success: /*-secure-
{"userInfo":{"wl_directUpdateRealm":{"userId":"null","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"null","deviceId":"null"},"CustomAuthenticationRealm":{"isSuccessful":true,"userId":"maxadmin","attributes":{"Cookie":"JSESSIONID=0000-SkE1FAXWL8ftNRYI9N1xmN:-1; Path=\/; HttpOnly","AuthenticationDate":"Fri Jan 22 10:46:04 MYT 2016"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":null,"deviceId":"maxadmin"},"wl_authenticityRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"wl_remoteDisableRealm":{"userId":"null","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"null","deviceId":"null"},"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"userId":"c41pcfh3e92rspokaktj2be62i","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"c41pcfh3e92rspokaktj2be62i","deviceId":"c41pcfh3e92rspokaktj2be62i"},"wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":null,"attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":0,"displayName":null,"deviceId":null},"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":"0F2EE785-4184-4BC2-8C76-3B7CE840F38D","attributes":{"mobileClientData":"com.worklight.core.auth.ext.MobileClientData@dfd2569f"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"0F2EE785-4184-4BC2-8C76-3B7CE840F38D","deviceId":"0F2EE785-4184-4BC2-8C76-3B7CE840F38D"},"myserver":{"userId":"fcd2bad6-4ca1-4d40-9e02-ea3f23ec61c1","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"fcd2bad6-4ca1-4d40-9e02-ea3f23ec61c1","deviceId":"fcd2bad6-4ca1-4d40-9e02-ea3f23ec61c1"},"wl_anonymousUserRealm":{"userId":"fcd2bad6-4ca1-4d40-9e02-ea3f23ec61c1","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"fcd2bad6-4ca1-4d40-9e02-ea3f23ec61c1","deviceId":"fcd2bad6-4ca1-4d40-9e02-ea3f23ec61c1"}},"userPrefs":{},"gadgetProps":{"ENVIRONMENT":"iphone"}}*/
2016-01-22 10:46:51.691 WorkExecution[1689:755742] [DEBUG] [NONE] wlclient connect success
2016-01-22 10:46:51.737 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TIMER] PersistenceManager - add - Adding data into jsonstore - PlatformViewQueryResource: 65ms
2016-01-22 10:46:51.746 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TIMER] PersistenceManager _findRecordsOnStore: (ignore if querybase exists)PlatformViewQueryResource queryBase: null query: [{"__tempId":1453430764565}]: 8ms
2016-01-22 10:46:51.747 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TIMER] _JsonInMemoryFindMixin - _arrayFilter: 1ms
2016-01-22 10:46:51.747 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TIMER] PersistenceManager - _filterExactMatchesIfNeeded: 1ms
2016-01-22 10:46:52.357 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [MapHandler] showmap
2016-01-22 10:46:52.358 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [platform.map.MapFactoryHelper] providerUrl is blank, trying to find a localMapUrl...
2016-01-22 10:46:52.358 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [platform.map.MapFactoryHelper] localMapUrl found: Manhattan.tpk
2016-01-22 10:46:52.358 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [platform.map.MapFactory] creating new map platform.map.EsriMap
2016-01-22 10:46:52.434 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [platform.map.MapFactory] Found bridgeConstructor
2016-01-22 10:46:52.435 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [platform.map.EsriMap] bridgeConstructor: {"specificParameters":{"id":"aw16755748","adjustToTop":"true","iosMapAccessMethod":"useDocumentsFolder","layoutInsertAt":"map","localMapUrl":"Manhattan.tpk","artifactId":"WorkExecution.MapView_esri_true","provider":"esri","workOfflineResource":"workOrder","currentLocationMessage":"Current Location"}}
2016-01-22 10:46:52.435 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [platform.map.nativeBridge.NativeBridgeHelper] Sending request using
2016-01-22 10:46:52.435 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [platform.map.nativeBridge.NativeBridgeHelper]   mapType: esri
2016-01-22 10:46:52.435 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [platform.map.nativeBridge.NativeBridgeHelper]   action: bridgeConstructor
2016-01-22 10:46:52.435 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [platform.map.nativeBridge.NativeBridgeHelper] method do NOT have cache
2016-01-22 10:46:52.435 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [platform.map.nativeBridge.NativeBridgeHelper] deferred found!
2016-01-22 10:46:52.436 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [platform.map.MapPlugin] entering sendRequest...
2016-01-22 10:46:52.436 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [platform.map.MapPlugin] deferred is: [object Deferred]
2016-01-22 10:46:52.436 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [platform.map.MapPlugin] method is: [bridgeConstructor]
2016-01-22 10:46:52.436 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [platform.map.MapPlugin] action is: [esri:bridgeConstructor]
2016-01-22 10:46:52.436 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [platform.map.MapPlugin] parameters is: [object Object]
2016-01-22 10:46:52.437 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [platform.map.MapPlugin] Calling MapPlugin with deferred object
2016-01-22 10:46:52.438 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIMapPlugin respondsToSelector:]:26:super does not have a selector to esri:bridgeConstructor:
2016-01-22 10:46:52.438 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIMapPlugin respondsToSelector:]:33:Found a map selector for esri:bridgeConstructor:
2016-01-22 10:46:52.438 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIMapPlugin methodSignatureForSelector:]:49:Unable to find signature for selector esri:bridgeConstructor:
2016-01-22 10:46:52.438 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIMapPlugin methodSignatureForSelector:]:50:Try to forward invocation
2016-01-22 10:46:52.439 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIMapPlugin forwardInvocation:]:92:Processing forward invocation
2016-01-22 10:46:52.439 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIMapPlugin forwardInvocation:]:93:Invocation signature: <NSMethodSignature: 0x15541cd0>
2016-01-22 10:46:52.439 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIMapPlugin forwardInvocation:]:102:MainThread - command.callbackId: MapPlugin27923582
2016-01-22 10:46:52.439 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIMapPlugin forwardInvocation:]:112:Receiving cordova request esri:bridgeConstructor:
2016-01-22 10:46:52.440 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIMapPlugin forwardInvocation:]:113:MapType is: esri
2016-01-22 10:46:52.440 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIMapPlugin forwardInvocation:]:114:Method selector is: bridgeConstructor:
2016-01-22 10:46:52.440 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIMapPlugin forwardInvocation:]:115:BackgroundThread - command.callbackId: MapPlugin27923582
2016-01-22 10:46:52.440 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIMapPlugin forwardInvocation:]:118:Begin applying the license of esri map
2016-01-22 10:46:52.444 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIMapPlugin forwardInvocation:]:125:End of applying the license of esri map
2016-01-22 10:46:52.924 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIMapPlugin forwardInvocation:]:180:EsriMap instance created
2016-01-22 10:46:52.925 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIEsriMap loadSpecificParameters:]:114:map params {
    adjustToTop = true;
    artifactId = "WorkExecution.MapView_esri_true";
    currentLocationMessage = "Current Location";
    id = aw16755748;
    iosMapAccessMethod = useDocumentsFolder;
    layoutInsertAt = map;
    localMapUrl = "Manhattan.tpk";
    provider = esri;
    workOfflineResource = workOrder;
}
2016-01-22 10:46:52.926 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIEsriMap loadSpecificParameters:]:129:path resolved to load /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1E7497A1-72B5-410C-A1E3-A35995D725AB/Documents/Manhattan.tpk
2016-01-22 10:46:52.928 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIEsriMap loadSpecificParameters:]:132:tiledlayer loaded? 0
2016-01-22 10:46:52.928 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIEsriMap loadSpecificParameters:]:133:error on the tiledlayer? Cache at path '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1E7497A1-72B5-410C-A1E3-A35995D725AB/Documents/Manhattan.tpk' not found.
2016-01-22 10:46:52.928 WorkExecution[1689:755353] DEBUG: -[ISIEsriMap loadSpecificParameters:]:136:The map file /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1E7497A1-72B5-410C-A1E3-A35995D725AB/Documents/Manhattan.tpk for this view is not available.
2016-01-22 10:46:52.935 WorkExecution[1689:755353] THREAD WARNING: ['MapPlugin'] took '496.894043' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2016-01-22 10:46:52.951 WorkExecution[1689:755353] WARN: [platform.map.MapPlugin] failed to resolve, error message: [object Object]
2016-01-22 10:46:52.952 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] [platform.map.MapFactory] [object Object]
2016-01-22 10:46:52.952 WorkExecution[1689:755353] [TRACE] IN Image watch: HIDING
2016-01-22 10:46:52.952 WorkExecution[1689:755353] === Global promise rejection handling ===
2016-01-22 10:46:52.953 WorkExecution[1689:755353] === handled: true
2016-01-22 10:46:52.954 WorkExecution[1689:755353] Hiding the "Loading..." message in 8 seconds
2016-01-22 10:46:52.954 WorkExecution[1689:755353] === Global promise rejection handling ===
2016-01-22 10:46:52.954 WorkExecution[1689:755353] === handled: true
2016-01-22 10:46:52.955 WorkExecution[1689:755353] Hiding the "Loading..." message in 8 seconds
2016-01-22 10:46:53.668 WorkExecution[1689:755517] [DEBUG] [NONE] Piggybacking event transmission
2016-01-22 10:46:53.671 WorkExecution[1689:755695] [DEBUG] [NONE] Flush called
2016-01-22 10:47:00.939 WorkExecution[1689:755353] WARN: Loading message hidden by application = true
2016-01-22 10:47:00.939 WorkExecution[1689:755353] WARN: Loading message hidden
2016-01-22 10:47:00.940 WorkExecution[1689:755353] WARN: Loading message hidden by application = true
2016-01-22 10:47:00.940 WorkExecution[1689:755353] WARN: Loading message hidden
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

follow this link 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.5.0/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc_7.5.0/maps/t_configure_map_apps.html?lang=en

You need .tpk file on your device on right location,  One of the things you can look at for device is where you put your tpk ,

edit the app.xml and update the attribute localMapUrl="file://folder_structure/map_file_name.tpk" with the location and name of the map file on the mobile device. For example: localMapUrl="file://mnt/sdcard/basemaps/Manhattan.tpk" The folder /mnt/sdcard is a public folder that is accessible by any Android application.

for example on device you are putting your tpk part of /basemaps/Manhatton.tpk

Comment: Am using iPhone and I need to check only ONLINE maps. Please help in adding "providerUrl " instead of keeping the .tpk file in device.

Comment: I have added providerUrl in app.xml and getting map view but its not showing current location properly.
Also, For ArcGIS url, what need to pass for x/y/z.

Answer (score 0):

You need tpk file on device , follow 7.5.2 link 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.5.2/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc_7.5.2/maps/t_configure_map_apps.html?lang=en

From the maximoanywhere_home\MaximoAnywhere\apps\WorkExecution\artifact directory, edit the app.xml and update the attribute for the map control. You can also update the attribute by using the Anywhere Administration application if it is enabled.
For offline maps, update the LocalMapUrl attribute with the location and name of the TPK file on the mobile device. Also, for iOS devices, update the iosMapAccessMethod attribute to use either the Documents folder or the bundle.
For Android devices, this is androidLocalMapUrl="file://folder_path/map_file_name.tpk".
For iOS devices, this is iosLocalMapUrl="file://folder_path/map_file_name.tpk". You must also enter either useDocumentsFolder or useBundle for the iosMapAccessMethod attribute.
For online maps, set the providerUrl attribute. The value can be any valid ArcGIS tile service. If you do not set the providerUrl attribute, the user-defined TPK file is used.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the online maps working, you got to do the following:

- Enable Map View. Follow [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.6.0/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc/maps/t_configure_map_apps.html)
- Enable the cron task in Maximo. This is required in order to get the coordinates sent to the device properly. I believe you have missed this step. Follow this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPJLC_7.6.0/com.ibm.si.mpl.doc/maps/t_enable_crontask.html) for this.