# maximo Anywhere Map coordinates were not found

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

We are working with maximoAnywhere 7.5.2.0 mobile application. Currently I have to use onlien map with geolocation to display location. But still we are not able to get location. It just loads the map view.

I was trying the follow the guidelines given in this question:

[Maximo Anywhere Map Location Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006077/maximo-anywhere-map-location-issue)

But I got an error message on both my device and simulator. How can I solve this?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically your workorders don't have coordinates set, so the offline map will not try to display their location, nor your location.  Check the first 20 workorders of your query and make sure they have calculatedX and calculatedY coordinates set.

Comment: Scott, do you know if the `calculatedx` and `calculatedy` fields are only used for Anywhere? I'm trying to figure out how to populate them with an automation script. Related posts here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=e6388378-3fd4-49bd-9d3a-10860b26dc18 and here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=703f3933-bb4e-4778-b57e-428c43c2f424&ps=25